# Have Highcharts tooltip disappear on click

Tags: javascript, events, tooltip, highcharts

Here is my code example

http://jsfiddle.net/pradeepbhat92/42uUG/

What I'm trying to do is have the tooltip stay on the flag until the user either goes over to another flag or clicks outside of the tooltip/flag. Is this possible with highcharts?

The only clue I've found so far is this line

```
chart.tooltip.hide=function(){};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**

Remove `display: block` from your css.

**Second**

Revome `series` inside `plotOptions`, merge it with `flags`.

**Third**

You have to `trigger chart.tooltip.hide()` on `chart` click event and not on `flag`.

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    events: {
        click: function() {
            this.tooltip.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

**Fourth**

To prevent the tooltip on the other serie you have to check the serie, if it's the serie you want to prevent you can simple return `false`.
So, to do it add the following if statement inside the tooltip formatter.

```
if( this.points && this.points[0].series.options.id == 'dataseries' ) {
    return false;
}
```

[**workin demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/8JpT3/)

Comment: thanks really easy to understand answer,and the working demo was a nice add on.